# Location of settings file for Roundcube

Tags: webmail, roundcube

Could someone tell me where those settings (of webmail/roundcube) are saved into a file?
Thank you!
[check this link please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6as3.jpg)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6as3.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can find the settings in Roundcube Web directory > config/defaults.inc.php

Ref Link : [RoundcubeMail Github](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/blob/master/config/defaults.inc.php)

```
// Interface layout. Default: 'widescreen'.
//  'widescreen' - three columns
//  'desktop'    - two columns, preview on bottom
//  'list'       - two columns, no preview
$config['layout'] = 'widescreen';

// default messages sort column. Use empty value for default server's sorting, 
// or 'arrival', 'date', 'subject', 'from', 'to', 'fromto', 'size', 'cc'
$config['message_sort_col'] = '';

// default messages sort order
$config['message_sort_order'] = 'DESC';

// These cols are shown in the message list. Available cols are:
// subject, from, to, fromto, cc, replyto, date, size, status, flag, attachment, priority
$config['list_cols'] = array('subject', 'status', 'fromto', 'date', 'size', 'flag', 'attachment');
```

But, it is not good idea to manipulate the **default.inc.php** file, rather you can copy the code in **config.inc.php** page which overrides the default.inc.php values.